# splash screen error with xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, ios7, ios5

I want to upload app to the store, but i'm facing this problem:
[image]

this is the images uploaded to `LaunchImage` :
[image]

and this is app general properties:
[image]

i have these warning:

```
: You're targeting iOS 8.0, but named colors can only be accessed from an Asset Catalog in iOS 11.0 and later.
```

and

```
 An iPhone Retina (4-inch) launch image for iOS 7.0 and later is required.
```

i don't know which additional sizes needed and how to add them,
what should i do?

Comment: Please check this: [How to fix Xcode Validation Error: “Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5”](https://medium.com/@oliviazyc/how-to-fix-xcode-validation-error-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-155f7ee70868)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below size images 

Portrait
iPhone

3.5 Inch => 640 x 960  
4.0 Inch => 640 x 1136 
4.7 Inch => 750 x 1334
5.5 Inch => 1242 x 2208
5.8 Inch => 1125 x 2436

iPad

1536 x 2048


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD6gh.png
```

Comment: How are you setting splash images.xcassets or default@

Comment: i can't understand what you mean, but i drag and drop images to images.xcassets and xcode set therm, the images name don't start with default@

Answer (score 0):

```
Please follow below steps: 

1. Project Target settings remove Launch Screen File
2. Enable Launch Image Source with Assets.xcassets
3. Add LaunchImage set in Assets.xcassets and assign correct size images

For ex Portrait Sizes:


iPhone

3.5 Inch => 640 x 960  
4.0 Inch => 640 x 1136 
4.7 Inch => 750 x 1334
5.5 Inch => 1242 x 2208
5.8 Inch => 1125 x 2436

iPad

1536 x 2048

4. Project Target change Launch Image Source to LaunchImage

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukSHj.png
```